# Game: Found a number in 5 attempts

Tags: java

Here the goal of the game: The **number to search** is `5` and there are `5` **attempts**.

The user enters a number...

if the number is not 5, the user can enter an other number. He has 5 attempts.

My problem: When I found the number to search in my first attempt, I again have to enter several attempts.

```
import java.util.*;



class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner enter = new Scanner (System.in);

    int choice_user = 0; 
    int number_to_search = 5; 
    int choice_user_number = 0;
    int number_attempt = 1;
    int i = 4;

    do{

      System.out.println("********Menu*******");
      System.out.println("1) - Start the game :");
      System.out.println("2) - Exit the game :");

      System.out.print("Enter your choice : ");
      choice_user = enter.nextInt();

      switch(choice_user){

        case 1: 
          System.out.println("Option 1 : ");

          while(i < 5){
            System.out.print("Enter your number : ");
            choice_user_number = enter.nextInt();

            if(choice_user_number > number_to_search){
              System.out.println("Smaller ! Attempt : " + number_attempt);
            }
            else if(choice_user_number < number_to_search){
              System.out.println("Bigger ! Attempt : " + number_attempt);
            }

            else{
              System.out.println("Bravo ! Attempt : " + number_attempt);
            }

            number_attempt++;
            i--;


          }
          break; 

        default:
          System.out.print("Exit... ");

      }

    } while(choice_user != 2);
  }
}
```

I don't understand my problem. Thank you for your help. 
I also shared my code here: https://repl.it/repls/WindingImpossibleKernelmode

Comment: The loop only stops when i < 5  is false. You want to stop it sooner. So either you add a `break;`statement to stop it, or you add an additional contion in the while loop like `while (i < 5 && !found`, and you make sure that found becomes true when the user has found the number.

Comment: @JB Nizet: Ok. Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove i variable, and use number_attempt to exit loop. When user achieved it, you must force to exit the loop, for example, setting number_attempt to 6

Also you must modify the loop condition to repeat until 5 times.

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner enter = new Scanner (System.in);

    int choice_user = 0; 
    int number_to_search = 5; 
    int choice_user_number = 0;
    int number_attempt = 1;

    do{

      System.out.println("********Menu*******");
      System.out.println("1) - Start the game :");
      System.out.println("2) - Exit the game :");

      System.out.print("Entrer your choice : ");
      choice_user = enter.nextInt();

      switch(choice_user){

        case 1: 
          System.out.println("Option 1 : ");
          number_attempt = 1; // set fo first attempt
          while(number_attempt <= 5){ // only has 5 attempts
            System.out.print("Enter your number : ");
            choice_user_number = enter.nextInt();

            if(choice_user_number > number_to_search){
              System.out.println("Smaller ! Attempt : " + number_attempt);
            }
            else if(choice_user_number < number_to_search){
              System.out.println("Bigger ! Attempt : " + number_attempt);
            }

            else{
              System.out.println("Bravo ! Attempt : " + number_attempt);
              number_attempt = 6; // force to exit the loop
            }

            number_attempt++;
          }
        break; 

        default:
          System.out.print("Exit... ");

      }

    } while(choice_user != 2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I understood. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are to possibilities: what you basically have to do is in your inner loop modifying something to get out of it.
You can achieve this by putting a `break;` into your if statement telling the user he got the answer or by setting `i=5;` which will also get you out of the loop.
Which one you take is more or less personal preference as some people don't like breaks though this takes one less compare operation as it won't check if the loop condition is still fulfilled.

Or you use the possibility suggested by Jose which is even better considering he saved one variable.

Edit: you might also need to consider setting choice to 2 in your default branch of the break.

Edit 2: your condition of your loop quoting `while (i < 5)` would always be true as you count down from 4. Initialize `int i=0;` and do `i++;` instead of `i--;`
Then set I back to 0 after winning

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanation. I understood my error.